# Understanding environment variable / shell syntax

Tags: terminal, zsh, git

I was just [following the install instructions for zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/master/INSTALL.md#oh-my-zsh) and I don't understand what part of the following command is doing:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-~/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions
```

- What does the `${ZSH_CUSTOM:- ...}` do?
- Why not just clone directly into `~/.oh-my-zsh/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter substitution `${variable:-value}` would be replaced by `$variable` if that variable was set and not empty, otherwise it's replaced by `value`. This is [a standard parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

In this case, it allows the user to set `ZSH_CUSTOM` to where they keep their oh-my-zsh customisation files, or to not set it and use the default location of `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom`.

Not using this construct would make the life of users who have tailor made setups a bit awkward as they would have to either manually modify the command, or move the files to the correct place after installation (and possibly run the risk of having pre-existing files overwritten by `git clone`).